# Debug unit testcases with breakpoints while executing gulp

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, webstorm

Is it possible to debug unit testcases written using jasmine(for eg: filename.spec.js) with breakpoints in webstorm editor while executing the gulp command "gulp test".

I am using phantomjs as browser in karma.conf file.

Breakpoints which I have kept are not hitting but testcases executing successfully.Kindly provide some suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked here? https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

Comment: @shaun : I am new to this,Is Debugging node.js is relevant to debugging unit testcases? Since I tried the local configuration of nodejs and executed but this time none of testcases got executed.

Comment: Sorry, gulp is a Node app so I thought that would be relevant...but it looks like they have docs for debugging Karma and Jasmine as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/debugging-javascript-unit-tests.html

Comment: @shaun : thanks shaun tried karma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In webstorm 11.0.1 to debug the unit testcases by breakpoints for development purpose.

Run -> Edit configurations

click the plus sign and select karma

1) Give a desired name to the configuration(for eg:Karma Debug)

2) select your karma config file from the drop down

3) Browsers to start(Chrome) and click apply

In chrome browser install the jetbrains IDE support extension and put breakpoints in your unit testcases.

finally DEBUG using the created configuration(Karma Debug).